# How can I activate an element and deactivate others with Javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I’m working on a drop down FAQ where the user clicks the desire question and a hidden div containing the information is displayed. The piece of code I came up with only does that, displays or hides the clicked div. But I’m trying to do a function that one an user clicks the displayed information is hidden and the clicked one is shown. [activate one element and deactivate the rest] I do so through CSS adding/removing classes. I’m new to JS so there’s things that takes me longer. If anyone can help me out it’ll be amazing.

Here’s the JS code so far.

```
//Storing the buttons
const questions = document.getElementsByClassName(‘faq-list-item’)
//Storing the hidden div
const clic = document.querySelectorAll(‘q-answered’)

for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
   questions[i].addEventListener(‘click’,((e) => {
      return function() {
         if (clic[e].classList.contains(‘q-answered)) {
            clic[e].classList.replace(‘q-answered’, ‘q-answeredno’);
         } else if (clic[e].classList.contains(‘q-answeredno’)) {
            clic[e].classList.replace(‘q-answeredno’, ‘q-answered’);
         }
      }
   })(i))
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: First of all, this is not a valid javascript code. Second, is `q-answered` an element's tag name or a class name? because your querySelector suggests it's a tag name. What you'll need to do is loop through all `q-answered` elements and remove that class from them on each click

Comment: You'll want to examine your question posting workflow because you have `‘` and `’` quotes instead of `'`.  And some of them are mismatched.  Always prefer to cut and paste directly from a working copy of your code rather than typing it in again by hand, or via a word document or whatever auto-formatted those quotes.

Comment: Please specify what exactly your question is. SO isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet below adds a click listener to each element of a list. The listener swaps the classes on every element, swapping to `'q-answered'` if the element was clicked, swapping to `'q-answeredno'` for the others.

(I think that's what you mean by "activating" some and "deactivating" the rest)

```js
// remove fromClass if it's on the element. add toClass
function switchClass(element, fromClass, toClass) {
  if (element.classList.contains(fromClass))
    element.classList.replace(fromClass, toClass);
  else
    element.classList.add(toClass);
}

const questions = [...document.getElementsByClassName('faq-list-item')];

questions.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    questions.forEach(q => {
      q === el ? switchClass(q, 'q-answeredno', 'q-answered') : switchClass(q, 'q-answered', 'q-answeredno')
    })
  });
});
```

```css
.q-answered {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.q-answeredno {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="faq-list-item q-answered">Item 0</li>
  <li class="faq-list-item q-answeredno">Item 1</li>
  <li class="faq-list-item q-answeredno">Item 2</li>
  <li class="faq-list-item q-answeredno">Item 3</li>
  <li class="faq-list-item q-answeredno">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```